# Did I do something wrong in this Community?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I started Stack Overflow not long ago, days.

I asked eight times on this site. I think my questions are not good reputation from many peoples because of language problems. But some of the good people replied to my question, and it was very useful for me...

Then, one day I could't post any more questions, and I could see some message on the Ask Question page like this:

---

> You have reached your question limit
>   It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!
>
> You've asked 8 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.
>
> It's been 4 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 3 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.
>
> Recommended reading:
>
> - tips on asking great questions as well as our guidance on
> - which questions are allowed here
>
> Additional advice
>
> - Examining highly-scored questions in the tags that interest you is a great way to study how to ask better questions, that also get better answers much sooner!
> - We don’t demand perfection, but please make sure you use proper grammar, spelling and capitalization, it really helps!
> - Improve downvoted questions rather than deleting them.
> - Do not delete your account, create new accounts, or otherwise attempt to circumvent these restrictions.
> - Do not contact us regarding these restrictions, they cannot be lifted.
>
> Failure to heed this advice may increase the severity of these restrictions.
>
> For more information
>
> See: Why won’t the system allow me to ask questions for several days?
>
> It sometimes takes a few attempts at a good question in order to fully learn how our system works, and what the community expects from folks seeking answers. Just do your best to make sure you've improved the quality of your existing questions, and we'll see you in 3 days!

---

I can not understand this message. How can I ask again on this site?

Is this message for blocking people who have a linguistic problem?

Who easily explain these problems?

Comment: ㄴ ask what? should I find like post box?

Comment: Which part of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34487713/1) did you think was OK? You can't blame such a profound misunderstanding of this network on simple language issues.

Comment: ah.. is not good Emoticon in this site?

Comment: @Kyu _"ah.. is not good Emoticon in this site?"_ No! ;-) ...

Comment: @Kyu btw are you from Japan? (Because of your name and those emoticons I can guess it but not sure, I'm studying japanese and got to know them). If so, then there's a site of stack overflow in [japanese](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/) where I think language problems might not be a problem anymore. And as they told you, you should show a bit more effort before asking, that way you'll get better answers (and probably upvotes! :D)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Can't tell if you're being serious or not? You say *No* but then immediately follow with a smiley face.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I guess he's pretty serious (*＾▽＾)／ (It's ok to use them, but not abuse the use of them like in the linked question by jonrsharpe)

Comment: @Frakcool Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ that, and he's posting an emoticon in a comment, not in a question. Very different

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ You're welcome. It's pretty common here in meta to see this kind of "funny" comments, because they answer OP's question while being kind or (any synonym for that (sorry not an english native lol))

Comment: @Patrice, I completely understand that. I was actually a bit surprised that they're *allowed* anywhere.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ in comments, people won't care enough. The problem is mostly that, on questions, this is just unecessary fluff taking away attention from the basic question asked. On comments, they don't matter (the fact comments are second class citizens on Stack comes into mind here)

Comment: Thanks for Everyone... I hardly read and understood This site Rule. helped by @Patrice  and I little bit under stood this site rule...and how to Ask Question..

Answer (score 10):

Your questions are not poorly received because of language problems, they are poorly received because of lack of research effort i.e. you're not looking to see whether a similar question already exists or showing that you've made some attempt in solving the issue yourself. You may have made such efforts but you're not including that in the question.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487713/insert-background-music-file-in-app) has a comment to that effect...

> Also, it's helpful to provide code showing what you've tried, beyond merely importing the AVFoundation module.

If you edit your existing posts and successfully fix the problems that caused them to be downvoted in the first place they may get upvotes instead of downvotes at which point you'll be able to ask more questions.

Comment: Nobody do not know my situation.. I found and research many time. anyway but i can understand You and other peoples say.. that is **First**my research is not enough. **second** my question is not described in detail. **My question is Duplication.**. So I blocked in this site.. it is very Hard to join this community. any way thanks for comment..

Comment: @kyu it is not very hard. Did you read the help center, understood the rules, made sure you respected them? The info is there. Just read up on it.  And when someone comments "it would be helpful to add x"... then try to add x. Also, you're jot banned (yet). You just have to wait.